# Can Electric field line form a right angle?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electricity, electric-fields

Can Electric field line form a right angle ? something that look like the letter L..
please be as rigorous as possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to happen, the electric field at the point where the field line is forming the right angle would have to be undefined. This can only happen if there is a divergent density of charge at the point. Thus, strictly speaking, the electric field line doesn't have a well-defined existence at such a point. However,  if one must, one can arrange many such situations where there are multiple field lines in the neighborhood of such a point which would be perpendicular. A cute example is provided by `@probablysomeone`.

Comment: you have not provided a link for the example

Comment: @annav Ah, thanks. I'll have to change that part I guess, it was an answer on this post itself but probably someone deleted it.